# Architectures with 2-bytes (or more) atomic endianness

Tags: c++, c, integer, endianness, cpu-word

Until recently, I thought that by specifying if an architecture is either `big-endian` or `little-endian` we would cover most systems (except `middle-endian` but these systems are not very common). But then, I read that the endianness "atomics" can be greater than bytes so that these system :

- little endian with 1 byte atomic
- little endian with 2 bytes atomic

will encode integers in different ways.

**Question:** How common systems with atomics equal or greater than two are?

Additional questions

- Can the atomic size depends on the type of integer (for example different atomics for `uint32_t` and `uint64_t`)?
- Do I have the guarantee that a `char` is always 1-byte long even on system with 2-bytes endianness atomics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to worry about the particular native byte order of your machine, you can use functions such as `ntohl()` and `ntohs()`, or just read one byte at a time.

There isn't any guarantee that `char` is exactly 8 bits wide (see `<limits.h>` to check the number), but `char` is guaranteed to be at least 8 bits wide (so that a `char[]` can hold a UTF-8 string) and `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.  If you need an exact 8-bit-wide type, use `uint8_t`.